# Is Django REST Framework's HyperlinkedRelatedField unable to reference url patterns with multiple kwargs?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a REST api url endpoint that represents a `Song` within an `Album`:

```
/api/album/(?P<album_id>)/song/(?P<id>)/
```

and I want to refer to it from another resource, e.g. `Chart` that contains Top-1000 songs ever. Here's an implementation of `ChartSerializer`:

```
class ChartSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    songs = HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        queryset=Song.objects.all(),
        view_name='api:song-detail',
        lookup_field='id'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Chart
        fields = ('songs', )
```

Clearly, I can pass `id` as `lookup_field`, but it seems to me that I won't be able to pass `album_id` by any means. I'm looking into [HyperlinkedModelSerializer.get_url()](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/relations.py#L275) method:

```
def get_url(self, obj, view_name, request, format):
    """
    Given an object, return the URL that hyperlinks to the object.
    May raise a `NoReverseMatch` if the `view_name` and `lookup_field`
    attributes are not configured to correctly match the URL conf.
    """
    # Unsaved objects will not yet have a valid URL.
    if hasattr(obj, 'pk') and obj.pk in (None, ''):
        return None

    lookup_value = getattr(obj, self.lookup_field)
    kwargs = {self.lookup_url_kwarg: lookup_value}
    return self.reverse(view_name, kwargs=kwargs, request=request, format=format)
```

As you can see, it constructs kwargs for reverse url lookup from scratch and doesn't allow to pass additional parameters to it. Am I right that this is not supported?

**UPDATE**:
Found a reference to this problem in the issue list of DRF: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3204

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the answer is YES. There is even a paragraph about this issue in the DRF documentation:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-hyperlinked-fields